# Bootstrap Weld in a Spring Boot environment

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, cdi, weld

Does anyone know a way to bootstrap Weld in a Spring Boot Jar application with embedded Tomcat.

I have tried to use org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener with

```
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener; 

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public Listener weldListener()
  {
    return new Listener();
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: WELD-ENV-001104: Cannot get StandardContext from ServletContext.
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.WeldForwardingInstanceManager.getStandardContext(WeldForwardingInstanceManager.java:104) ~[weld-servlet-2.4.6.Final.jar:2.4.6.Final]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.WeldForwardingInstanceManager.getStandardContext(WeldForwardingInstanceManager.java:101) ~[weld-servlet-2.4.6.Final.jar:2.4.6.Final]
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you try with Weld 3.x?  Just wondering, why are you trying to run both Weld and Spring Boot in the same runtime?

Comment: Have you tried what is described in chapter 17.3.1.2 in Weld docs? See [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_tomcat)

Comment: @JohnAment let me answer you with a question, why not? IMHO CDI is a far better contexts and injection manager than Spring. I tried Weld 3.x with the same result. I found however a solution that I'll post here as an answer to my own question.

Comment: I was asking more to understand what your goal was.  There are alternatives to running lightweight "microservices" based on CDI.  You can look at microprofile.io, https://github.com/apache/meecrowave and even my own pluggable Hammock https://github.com/hammock-project

Comment: Although one of our goals is to build microservices applications, we want also to pack JSF applications into a jar file to avoid unnecessary deploy issues in customers with a single web application.

Comment: Won't you have a problem with both CDI (beans.xml scans everything Java EE spec like JPA beans etc.,) and Spring containers (component scanning packages) owning and managing the same beans?

Answer (score 5):

Finally I managed to bootstrap Weld in a Boot Spring application that uses an embedded Tomcat.

There are some problems related to both the Tomcat container that Weld uses and the management of the BOOT-INF entries in the Boot Spring generated jar. Some of the problems seem bugs and the other ones are related to the way Spring Boot generates the application jar file.

Weld uses Java Services to register a class that extends `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.AbstractContainer` that is used to attach the Weld annotations processor to the corresponding servlet container. In the case of Tomcat this class creates a `org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager` that replaces the standard `InstanceManager` that the servlet container uses.

The new `InstanceManager` is the class `org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.WeldForwardingInstanceManager`, this class has a method:

```
private static StandardContext getStandardContext(ServletContext context)
```

that uses introspection to obtain a `StandardContext` from a private field of the passed `ServletContext`. In the case of Tomcat Embedded the passed ServletContext is an instance of `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.NoPluggabilityServletContext` that no has the same field and is not an `ApplicationContextFacade` that is what this method expect.

I modified this method to deal with this situation. So I wrote a new `WeldForwardingInstanceManager`class, `MyWeldForwardingInstanceManager`, changing the `getStandardContext(ServletContext context)` method and adding two methods `getContextFieldValue(E obj)` and `getContextFieldValue(String fieldname, E obj)` instead of the existing `getContextFieldValue(E obj, Class<E> clazz)` method:

```
private static StandardContext getStandardContext(ServletContext context)
{
    try
    {
        // Hack into Tomcat to replace the InstanceManager using
        // reflection to access private fields
        try
        {
            ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext)getContextFieldValue(context);
            return (StandardContext)getContextFieldValue(appContext);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
        {
            ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext)getContextFieldValue("sc", context);
            ApplicationContext appContext = (ApplicationContext)getContextFieldValue(servletContext);
            return (StandardContext)getContextFieldValue(appContext);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw TomcatLogger.LOG.cannotGetStandardContext(e);
    }
}

private static <E> Object getContextFieldValue(E obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
{
    return getContextFieldValue(CONTEXT_FIELD_NAME, obj);
}

private static <E> Object getContextFieldValue(String fieldname, E obj) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field field = SecurityActions.lookupField(obj.getClass(), fieldname);
    SecurityActions.ensureAccessible(field);
    return field.get(obj);
}
```

The SecurityAction class has to be copied to the same package because it has package visibility.

And a new TomcatContainer is needed:

```
package mypackage;

import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.*;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.logging.TomcatLogger;

public class EmbeddedTomcatContainer extends AbstractContainer
{
    public static final Container INSTANCE = new EmbeddedTomcatContainer();

    private static final String TOMCAT_REQUIRED_CLASS_NAME = "org.apache.catalina.connector.Request";

    @Override
    protected String classToCheck()
    {
        return TOMCAT_REQUIRED_CLASS_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContainerContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            MyWeldForwardingInstanceManager.replaceInstanceManager(context.getServletContext(), context.getManager());
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(context.getServletContext().getAttribute(EnhancedListener.ENHANCED_LISTENER_USED_ATTRIBUTE_NAME)))
            {
                TomcatLogger.LOG.allInjectionsAvailable();
            }
            else
            {
                TomcatLogger.LOG.listenersInjectionsNotAvailable();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TomcatLogger.LOG.unableToReplaceTomcat(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And then is necessary to add a Service to load the EmbeddedTomcatContainer at startup. This is done adding a file with name `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Container` to the `services` folder of the `META-INF` folder of your applicaction. The contents of this file is the fully qualified name of the MyWeldForwardingInstanceManager class. In this case:

```
mypackage.MyWeldForwardingInstanceManager
```

These changes allow to bootstrap Weld, running the application inside Eclipse works with no problem, but fails when trying to run he application from a jar file packaged using the `repackage` goal of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

To make it work when using the packaged jar file you have to change two classes of Weld.

The first one is `org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.FileSystemBeanArchiveHandler`. It seems that there is a bug in the `getUrl()` method of the include class ZipFileEntry because it no adds a Jar separator when building the URL for an embedded jar file. So its needed to change it to:

```
@Override
public URL getUrl() throws MalformedURLException
{
    return new URL(archiveUrl + (archiveUrl.endsWith(".jar") ? JAR_URL_SEPARATOR : "") + name);
}
```

The second one is `org.jboss.weld.environment.util.Files`, this class has a method `filenameToClassname` that has to be modified to taking into account that the classes of the Spring Boot project are placed inside the folder `BOOT-INF/classes` and the Boot Spring loads them from it, but the Weld code thinks that these classes are loaded from the root. Once modified the method looks like:

```
public static String filenameToClassname(String filename)
{
    filename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf(CLASS_FILE_EXTENSION)).replace('/', '.').replace('\\', '.');
    if (filename.startsWith("BOOT-INF.classes."))
        filename = filename.substring(BOOT_INF_CLASSES.length());
    return filename;
}
```

After all these modifications have been done Weld starts with no problem and all the CDI annotations work in a Jar packaged Spring Boot application.

**EDIT**:

In order to avoid problems with libraries like Omnifaces 2.x that use Weld and are initialized when JSF starts, is better to initialize Weld using a servlet container initializer instead of a servlet context listener as suggested by @BalusC the author of Omnifaces. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474573/1907872).

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated. Through a lot of trial and error, just include the javassist.jar and putting all my application files in a jar so there is nothing in BOOT-INF/classes ended up working for me. I used weld 3.0.1